# Regex to match a fully qualified url exactly like https://merchant.com while in place of merchant it can be any letter

Tags: java, regex

I need a regex for the url https://example.com while in place of **example** it can be any letter

I tried `https:\/\/[a-z]\.[a-z]` but is only accepting the first letter in example and first letter in com which is `https://e.c` (accepting this with above regex) but I want it to accept whole url(https://example.com) as mentioned in the question.

Comment: you can try `https:\/\/[a-z]*.com`, the `*` means any number of tokens

Comment: `[a-z]` will indeed only match one character. That matches the spec.

Comment: @Bentaye It is working I was missing *  Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason it is only matching the first character is because you haven't specified a *quantifier*.

Thus, a *character class* will only match one character, of the specified values.

```
https://[a-z]+(?:\.[a-z]+)+
```

This is matching an *a-z* character, one or more, followed by a repeating pattern of, a single dot character, an *a-z* character, one more.

For example, this will match these values.

```
https://example.com
https://abc.example.com
https://www.abc.example.com
```

Answer (score -1):

try this as your pattern for the response you want this will be good.

```
https:\\/\\/\\w+\\.com
```